# Redactor - got to custom URL on submit

Tags: redactor, redactor.js

I have page with multiple forms, which are hidden based on what link is active. One of these forms is using redactor and I want to send the user back to this page with the redactor form open on submit. By default the page refreshes on submit and it shows the default form for that page. I couldn't find anything about this in the docs. If anyone knows how to accomplish this please let me know. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve this you need to use `window.location.hash` with this you can send a hash variable to the URL when you click on the link to get to your form.

The urlHash works as follows:

```
var UrlHashVal = window.location.hash.substr(1); //get the hash value and store as a var
$('form').hide(); //hide all forms by default
$('form#' + UrlHashVal).show(); //show the form whose id matches the hash value
```

What this does is enable you to send a link to someone, like `http://ucanstayatthe.ym.ca#myForm` and it will open that page with `form#myForm` on display.

Now all we have to do is enable this urlHash to work within the page as well. On the page we show/hide the forms based on links. All we need to do is write the formID to the URL from the link. To do this simply add the fromID to your href eg. "#myForm". Now when you click that link it will display #myform at the end of the windowURL.

This solves all of the problems because now when the page refreshes on the Redactor submit, it will reload the URL including the hashValue that you have written to it. SO instead of reloading `http://ucanstayatthe.ym.ca` it will reload `http://ucanstayatthe.ym.ca#myForm` which in turn will show the correct from.

Bingo